# Onsubmit javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi I have an html page that has a `form` in it, and I would like that when the `form` is clicked, an alert box pops up and says "thank you for getting in touch" all using javascript here is my code.

PS. As you will notice I have the `form` validating when submitted. I would like the top javascript alert box to be added in addition to the validation.

```
<form id="contact" onsubmit="checkContactForm(); return false;" onreset="resetForm();" action="">
  <p>Fill in the form below to send me a message!</p>    

  <div id="errormessage"></div>

  <p>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" onfocus="resetField(this);" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="email">E-mail address:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" onfocus="resetField(this);" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="message">Your Message:</label>
    <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="5" cols="25" onfocus="resetField(this);"></textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
    <button type="submit">Send Message</button>
    <button type="reset">Reset Form</button>
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you add your javascript?

Comment: Is the HTML you posted wrapped inside of a `form` element?

Comment: uhm it wont let me add either but the form i just posted is inside the html document, and the javascript file just contains my validation for the form thats all

Comment: Presuming that resetField(this) clears the input field, just imagine a user who typo'd their e-mail address and goes back to fix it - they click/tab into the input and now they have to type their entire e-mail again. Potentially even more troubling if they write a long message but go to revise it, and it gets cleared out.

Answer (score 1):

Try and example on [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrk1989/yXuhD/)

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body >
    <div id="errormessage"></div>
    <form id="new">
      <p>
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" " />
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="email">E-mail address:</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" " />
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="message">Your Message:</label>
        <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="5" cols="25"></textarea>
      </p>
      <p>
        <button  onClick="aler()">Send Message</button>
        <button type="reset">Reset Form</button>
      </p>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function aler(){
        alert("thank you for getting in touch" );
        document.getElementById("new").submit();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This shows an alert-box when submitted

```
<div id="errormessage"></div>
<form action="#" onsubmit="alert('Thank you for getting in touch');">
<p>
  <label for="name">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" onfocus="resetField(this);" />
</p>
<p>
  <label for="email">E-mail address:</label>
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" onfocus="resetField(this);" />
</p>
<p>
  <label for="message">Your Message:</label>
  <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="5" cols="25" onfocus="resetField(this);"></textarea>
</p>
<p>
  <button type="submit">Send Message</button>
  <button type="reset">Reset Form</button>
</p>
</form>
```